# MySQL sum return 0 by default

Tags: mysql, sum

I have an issue using the sum functionnality. So basically, I have 2 tables, **paiment_type** and **bills**. 
In the **bills** table, I have a foreign key name **fk_paiement_type** which allow me to know what kind of paiement was used for this particular bills.

When printing statistics, I'm doing this to get the total by paiement type :

```
SELECT 
  pt.name,
  SUM(f.total_ttc) AS total_mode 
FROM
  bills AS f 
  INNER JOIN paiement_type AS pt 
    ON pt.id = f.fk_paiement_type 
WHERE (
    f.created BETWEEN '2013-01-10' 
    AND '2013-01-10'
  ) 
  AND (
    f.type LIKE 'facture' 
    OR f.type LIKE ''
  ) 
GROUP BY f.fk_paiement_type
```

This code works well but I have actually 3 differents paiement type and sometimes only 2 of them were used during the day and I still want to display it same if it does not exists.

EDIT : I already tried to use IFNULL functionnality but it didn't work. The fk_paiement_type from the bills table will sometimes return only 2 values who match the paiement_type table. I think my problem come from here :

```
INNER JOIN paiement_type AS pt ON pt.id = f.fk_paiement_type
```

Any idea?

EDIT2 :

My table structure are as follow :

```
**Bills Table**

id (int), 
fk_paiement_type (int), 
ref (varchar), 
fk_client (int), 
tss (double), 
total_ttc (double), 
type (varchar), 
created (datetime)

**Paiement_type Table**

id (int), 
name (varchar)
```

I tried your last answer but it still didn't work. For now, I just bypass this issue in my Java code but I would love to have a "clean" way to do it.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 7):

Here it is use ifnull

```
SELECT 
  pt.name,
  IFNULL(SUM(f.total_ttc),0) AS total_mode 
FROM
  factures AS f 
  INNER JOIN paiement_type AS pt 
    ON pt.id = f.fk_paiement_type 
WHERE (
    f.created BETWEEN '2013-01-10' 
    AND '2013-01-10'
  ) 
  AND (
    f.type LIKE 'facture' 
    OR f.type LIKE ''
  ) 
GROUP BY f.fk_paiement_type
```

Edit :

```
SELECT 
  pt.name,
  SUM(f.total_ttc) AS total_mode 
FROM
  bills AS f 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM paiement_type GROUP BY fk_paiement_type) AS pt ON pt.id = f.fk_paiement_type 
WHERE (f.created BETWEEN '2013-01-10' AND '2013-01-10') AND (f.type LIKE 'facture' OR f.type LIKE '') 
GROUP BY f.fk_paiement_type
```

I think multiple results are joined when you are using inner join so restrict inner join to fetch only 1 record per group

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've been trying the IFNULL function but it still does not work. Maybe something I missed in my table structure? Because fk_paiement_type only return 2 paiements type. How to change the query to be able to get the total for each paiement type?

Comment: it is difficult to predict unless you post the structure of table and output data

Comment: INNER JOIN? Surely you want a LEFT OUTER JOIN!?!

Comment: Hi, I tried but it still didn't work...I updated my post (EDIT2) with my table structure, maybe it can help... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT 
    f.thename,
     f.total_mode 
    FROM (SELECT name as thename , SUM(total_ttc) AS total_mode  from bills 
          WHERE (
           f.created BETWEEN '2013-01-10' 
           AND '2013-01-10'
          ) 
           AND (
                f.type LIKE 'facture' 
             OR f.type LIKE ''
               ) GROUP BY fk_paiement_type  ) f
    INNER JOIN paiement_type AS pt 
    ON pt.id = f.fk_paiement_type
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but it still didn't work...I updated my post (EDIT2) with my table structure, maybe it can help... Thank you

Comment: Hi, I got this error : #1054 - Unknown column 'f.fk_paiement_type' in 'on clause'